# Showing Hamiltonian systems cannot have any attracting fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics

I wonder about showing conservative, hamiltonian systems cannot have any attracting fixed points.

For example

1. Definition. Let , be a smooth real-valued function of two variables. Then a
   system of the form

   $\dot{x}=\frac {\partial H}{\partial y}$

   $\dot{y}=-\frac {\partial H}{\partial x}$

is called a Hamiltonian system and the function H is called the Hamiltonian.
(a) Show that for any Hamiltonian system , $H(x,y)$ is a conserved quantity.
(b) Show that Hamiltonian systems cannot have any attracting fixed points.
(c) Convert the equation $m\ddot{x} + kx = 0$ into a dynamical system and construct
the associated Hamiltonian function H.
,

first thing is

$\frac {dH(x,y)}{dt} = \frac {\partial H}{\partial x}*\frac {\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac {\partial H}{\partial y}*\frac {\partial y}{\partial t}=-\dot{y}\dot{x}+\dot{x}\dot{y}$

when i show the "cannot attracting fixed points" i made $\frac {\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$ and found it equals $-\frac {\partial y}{\partial x}$ but i cant make clear it

Comment: Could you add some context and show what you have tried yourself to showthis?